# yaml octal integer generate errors

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, python-3.5

In my YAML file I have the below entry:

```
- type: dir
  name: .ssh
  chmod: 0o700
```

According to the [YAML 1.2 specification](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) section 3.2.1.3 the `0o700` is the way to specify octals (there is also an example in section 2.4)

However when I process the loaded file and do:

```
import os
import yaml
filename = "in.yml"

with open(filename) as fp:
    for e in yaml.load(open(filename)):
        if e['type'] == 'dir':
            os.mkdir(e['name'], e['chmod'])
```

I get `TypeError: an integer is required`. What is going wrong here?

I am using Python 3.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong is that you assume that your YAML library supports the latest version 1.2. That YAML version is from 2009, but you are using PyYaml and that still only supports 1.1. From the non-activity the last few years it seems to be a dead project, so don't expect this to be solved any time soon.

You can add

```
from yaml.resolver import Resolver

Resolver.add_implicit_resolver(
    'tag:yaml.org,2002:int',
    re.compile(r'''^(?:[-+]?0b[0-1_]+
               |[-+]?0o?[0-7_]+
               |[-+]?0[0-7_]+
               |[-+]?(?:0|[1-9][0-9_]*)
               |[-+]?0x[0-9a-fA-F_]+
               |[-+]?[1-9][0-9_]*(?::[0-5]?[0-9])+)$''', re.X),
    list('-+0123456789'))
```

in your program to add recognition of `0o123` kinda octals (it also still recognizes the 1.1 octals).

Please note that the above **only** works for Python 3, as PyYaml has different code for Python 2.

You should also consider using `pathlib.Path` types and their `.mkdir()` instead of `os.mkdir()`

Comment: ThanX. Do you know if there is a library for Python3 that is non-dead?

Comment: I looked at ruamel.yaml a long time ago, it at least had a single code base at that time. Not sure what its status is now.

Answer (score 3):

Install [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml/0.11.8)  ( `pip install ruamel.yaml` ). It defaults to loading 1.2 as documented [here](http://yaml.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pyyaml.html#yaml-1-2-support):

> unless the YAML document is loaded with an explicit version==1.1 or the document starts with:
>
> % YAML 1.1
>
> , ruamel.yaml will load the document as version 1.2.

and

> YAML 1.2 no longer accepts strings that start with a 0 and solely consist of number characters as octal, you need to specify such strings with 0o[0-7]+ (zero + lower-case o for octal + one or more octal characters).